# GLSL Uniforms are not getting defined

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I was designing a shader for multi-lights, and a function that handles the light creation.
The lights are saved inside a struct uniform array and the quantity of lights in an int uniform called 'light_quantity'.

This is the function that creates the light:

```
int Game::AllocLight(LIGHT_TYPE mylight,float radius,glm::vec3 position,glm::vec3 direction,glm::vec4 ambient,glm::vec4 specular,glm::vec4 diffuse,bool status,int in_pos){

if(number_lights + 1 > MAX_LIGHTS || in_pos > MAX_LIGHTS){
    return -1;
}
int newindex;
if(in_pos==-1){
    newindex = number_lights++;
}else{
    newindex=in_pos;
}

std::string as = std::to_string((unsigned long long)newindex);
// LightBase name
string light_base_name = "lights_a[" + as + "]";

GLint renderit_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".renderit")).c_str());

GLint ambient_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".ambient_light")).c_str());
GLint diffuse_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".diffuse_light")).c_str());
GLint specular_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".specular_light")).c_str());

GLint radius_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".radius")).c_str());

GLint position_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".light_position")).c_str());
GLint direction_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".light_direction")).c_str());

GLint type_uniform = glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),string(light_base_name + string(".light_type")).c_str());

int light_type;
switch(mylight){
    case POINT_TYPE:
        light_type=1;
    break;
    case DIRECTIONAL_TYPE:
        light_type=2;
    break;
    case AREA_TYPE:
        light_type=3;
    break;
    case SUN_TYPE:
        light_type=4;
    break;
}

glUniform1i(renderit_uniform,status);

glUniform4f(ambient_uniform,ambient.w,ambient.x,ambient.y,ambient.z);
glUniform4f(diffuse_uniform,diffuse.w,diffuse.x,diffuse.y,diffuse.z);
glUniform4f(specular_uniform,specular.w,specular.x,specular.y,specular.z);

glUniform1f(radius_uniform,radius);

glUniform3f(position_uniform,position.x,position.y,position.z);
glUniform3f(direction_uniform,direction.x,direction.y,direction.z);

glUniform1i(type_uniform,light_type);

glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(main_program.GetId(),"light_quantity"),number_lights);

return newindex;
}
```

MAX_LIGHTS: A macro defined with #defined, it's an int...
The problem is, that the uniforms are not getting defined as they are supposed to.

Here is my fragment shader (the vertex shader is not important in this problem, I think...)

```
#version 330 core
struct LightBase{
int renderit;

vec4 ambient_light;
vec4 specular_light;
vec4 diffuse_light;

float radius;

vec3 light_position;
vec3 light_direction;

int light_type;
};
struct MaterialBase{
vec4 ambient_affect;
vec4 specular_affect;
vec4 diffuse_affect;
float shining;

float mirror;

int light_affect;
};
in vec3 VertexPos;
in vec3 Normal;
uniform int light_quantity;
uniform LightBase lights_a[50];
uniform MaterialBase material;
uniform float usingTex;
uniform sampler2D texturemap;
in vec2 UVs;
in vec4 Colors;
out vec4 color;
void main(){

vec4 texture_u = texture(texturemap,UVs).rgba * usingTex;
vec4 color_u = Colors * (1.0f-usingTex);

vec4 final_color = color_u+texture_u;
for(int i=0;i<light_quantity;i++){
//if(lights_a[i].renderit==1){ // This is commented for test if the "light_quantity" is getting defined.
    //if(lights_a[i].light_type==1){ // This is commented for test if the "light_quantity" is getting defined.
        // Point Type
        float attenuation = max(0.0,1.0-dot(lights_a[i].light_direction,lights_a[i].light_direction));

        vec3 L = normalize(lights_a[i].light_direction);
        vec3 N = normalize(Normal);
        vec3 V = normalize(-VertexPos);
        vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(L,N));

        float nDotL = max(0.0,dot(N,L));
        float rDotV = max(0.0,dot(R,V));

        vec4 ambient_result = lights_a[i].ambient_light * material.ambient_affect * attenuation;
        vec4 diffuse_result = lights_a[i].diffuse_light * material.diffuse_affect * nDotL * attenuation;
        vec4 specular_result = lights_a[i].specular_light * material.specular_affect * pow(rDotV,material.shining) * attenuation;

        vec4 this_colour = (ambient_result + diffuse_result + specular_result) * final_color;
        final_color = vec4(0,0,0,0); // this_colour; // vec4(0,0,0,0) for test if the "light_quantity" is getting defined.
    //} // This is commented for test if the "light_quantity" is getting defined.
//} // This is commented for test if the "light_quantity" is getting defined.

}

color = final_color;
}
```

Any Idea about why is this happening? I already tested a lot of times and I arrived to the conclution that the problems are the uniforms, what's happening? Are the uniforms that are not working?

Comment: Have you output the addresses returned by glGetUniformLocation? glGetUniformLocation will return -1 if it's not properly finding the location, then any attempts to set that uniform will silently fail.

Comment: Also I don't see you using the program. Try glUseProgram(main_program.GetId()); at the begining of the Game::AllocLight block, if it's not being done elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I checked the value returned from glGetUniformLocation, everything is fine, but the shader is not getting the value defined, I already tested it, also, I'm using the glUseProgram too....

Comment: I posted the function that adds the light information to the shader, the call of the glUseProgram, swap buffers, glGenBuffers, etc... Is being called correctly.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem: 50 lights seems a bit excessive. This is normally the time where one implements a deferred renderer and does 50 additive light passes.

Comment: Thanks... That's another thread, but. Talking about the quantity of the lights... How can I reduce the quantity of lights... If I need the sun light, the light bulbs lights.. etc etc?

Comment: I hope you understand swap buffers and genbuffers has nothing to do with assigning uniforms... yet uniform assignment will fail if you don't glUseProgram() first. "everything is fine, but the shader is not getting the value defined" that statement alone says everything's not fine. You really should post a driver version if you're only going to accept that it's a driver bug. And a driver bug is the only thing that would explain values simply disappearing between glUniformX and the shader when "everything is fine.".

Comment: Yup, sorry If I didn't know how to say what I wanted to say (My english...), Talking about my problem, my problem was exactly the one that you told on that comment, I followed your tip of using the glUseProbram  in the alloc light, but the id of the program was the real problem, the GL programming side was fine, but that main_program.GetId() was the problem. Thank you :D.
If you want, you can post that in an answer! I'll mark this question as 'answered'

Comment: Sure enough! Good to know it's working.